# Replace HDD with SSD on google cloud compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, geth

I am running GETH node on google cloud compute engine instance and started with HDD. It grows 1.5TB now. But it is damn slow. I want to move from HDD to SSD now.
How I can do that? 
I got some solution like : 
 - make a snapshot from the existing disk(HDD)
 - Edit the instance and attach new SSD with the snapshot made.
 - I can disconnected old disk afterwards.

One problem here I saw is : Example - If my HDD is 500GB, it is not allowing SSD of size less than 500GB. My data is in TBs now. It will cost like anything.

But, I want to understand if it actually works? Because this is a node I want to use for production. I already waiting too long and cannot afford to wait more.

One problem here I saw is : If my HDD is 500GB, it is not allowing SSD of size less than 500GB. My data is in TBs now. It will cost like anything.

Comment: Tip: Do NOT put a large amount of data on the OS boot disk. Create a new disk and add it to your instance. For some OS the boot drive cannot be larger than 2 TB. If you run out of space, you will need to know what you are doing to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use Zonal SSD persistent disks.

As standing in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#pdspecs)

> Each persistent disk can be up to 64 TB in size, so there is no need to manage arrays of disks to create large logical volumes.

Comment: Yup, will try Zonal SSD. Thanks!

Comment: @user3587417 if you think that my answer was helpful I would really appreciate if you could accept it :)!

Answer (score 0):

The description of the issue is confusing so I will try to help from my current understanding of the problem. First, you can use a booting disk snapshot to create a new booting disk accomplishing your requirements, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-root-persistent-disks#applying_snapshots). The size limit for persistent disk is of [2 TB](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-root-persistent-disks) so I don’t understand your comment about the 500 GB minimum size. If your disk have 1.5 TB then will meet the restriction.

Anyway, I don’t recommend having such a big disk as a booting disk. A better approach could be to use a smaller boot disk and expand the total capacity by attaching additional disks as needed, see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#ease_of_use).

Comment: 500GB was an example.